# How to query posts to include specific pages of one post type, and all pages of another post type?

Tags: get-posts, include, exclude

I'm having trouble figuring out how to query all posts from the post type "events", as well as including four specific pages in the loop.

If I use the "include" parameter, it only returns the specified pages. I figure I can use "exclude" to keep out what I don't want, but that's 50+ pages. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not quite any clean way to query for "this set of conditions oh and also something completely unrelated as well".

There are multiple ways to handle it, few of them being:

- query two things and deal with combining in template or around (easy, pain with pagination)
- hook into `WP_Query` and mess with SQL (easy... if you are good with SQL)
- query or otherwise produce combined set of post IDs, then query for that set (can get heavy, but pretty robust overall)